# Java application that uses ExecutorService never closes

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, completable-future

I am trying to write a program that will divide work up among several java worker threads.  The problem is that when I run it from the command line it never returns.  I do not get my prompt back, and must eventually ctrl-c the close the program.

I've simplified it to the following trivial case

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class TestExeServ {

    private class ExpensiveTask implements Callable<Integer>{
        private final String msg; 
        public ExpensiveTask(String str){
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer call()  {
            System.out.println( "My message was " + msg);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    private void run()
    {
        final ExecutorService exeServ = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        Future<Integer> result = exeServ.submit(new ExpensiveTask("Hello!") );
        try {
            System.out.println( " Task is done, it returned " + result.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println( "Start");       

        TestExeServ tes = new TestExeServ();
        tes.run();
        System.out.println( "Done");
    }       
}
```

The output of this program is

```
   djc@djc-linux:/local/mnt/workspace/TestExeServ/bin$ java TestExeServ
   Start
   my message was Hello!
    Task is done, it returned 1
   done
```

And that's it.  It hangs there.  No prompt.  If I remove the ExecutorService.submit line I get

```
   djc@djc-linux:/local/mnt/workspace/TestExeServ/bin$ java TestExeServ
   Start
   done
   djc@djc-linux:/local/mnt/workspace/TestExeServ/bin$
```

The program closes naturally.

Is there some cleanup task I need to be performing on the ExecutorService that I'm not doing properly?  I assumed the .get() call joined the threads.  Is that not the case?

Comment: you need to shutdown Executor

Comment: Or use a thread factory that produces daemon threads.

Comment: or set the flag allowCoreThreadTimeout [ThreadPoolExecutor application does not Finish](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30633698/217324)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must call [`ExecutorService#shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown--) or [`ExecutorService#shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow--) to terminate the executor's threadpool. Otherwise the threads will remain active thus preventing the JVM from termination.

From the [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) class Javadoc:

> An ExecutorService can be shut down, which will cause it to reject new tasks. Two different methods are provided for shutting down an ExecutorService. The `shutdown()` method will allow previously submitted tasks to execute before terminating, while the `shutdownNow()` method prevents waiting tasks from starting and attempts to stop currently executing tasks. Upon termination, an executor has no tasks actively executing, no tasks awaiting execution, and no new tasks can be submitted.

Note that, as a last resort, the `ThreadPoolExecutor` that you are using will shut itself down when it's garbage collected - its `finalize()` method invokes `shutdown()`. However, it's better not to rely on this and shut down the executor explicitly.

---

As @mre stated in the comment, I'll make it explicit - you can safely just call `exeServ.shutdown()` at the end of your `run()` method since `Future.get()` will block, so when the code execution is after the `get()` you don;t need the executor any more. However, if this is a simplified version of a more complex real-life scenario, you might need to find the right place to safely call `shutdown()`.

Comment: And `shutdownNow` is OK because `result.get` will block until the task is complete, otherwise you run the risk of canceling it.